# How to interpret/decode signalR requests and responses of blazor

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests, blazor, signalr

I need to make a python request to a blazor web server to do something as a bot. but the end-point server doesn't offer API for developers. so i sniff the browser network HTTP requests and it was not a json or human readable request. it's signalR and requests are sent binary and unreadable for human.
is there any solution to decode/understand the data so that i can build a python bot to send my request to the server without browser get involved?

Sample request that i sniff:

```
{"negotiateVersion":1,"connectionId":"mPtGjJ-copmHDi80CWjLew","connectionToken":"2tEI4GP4tq3gVE_dBzjGoQ","availableTransports":[{"transport":"ServerSentEvents","transferFormats":["Text"]},{"transport":"LongPolling","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]}]}
```

```
¢19À²DispatchEventAsyncÚ[{"eventHandlerId":654,"eventName":"click","eventFieldInfo":null},    {"detail":1,"screenX":713,"screenY":484,"clientX":675,"clientY":308,"offsetX":68,"offsetY":35,"pageX"    :675,"pageY":508,"button":0,"buttons":0,"ctrlKey":false,"shiftKey":false,"altKey":false,"metaKey":fal    se,"type":"click"}]
```

Comment: You can add a controller to your Blazor Server...

Comment: i dont have access to the server. if the arch of server was json/xhr it as easy to build python bot as client to send req to server. but now, i need to know how signalR works to  build evey request and send to server